# implementing methods in interface

Tags: java, generics, java-7

I have an implementation like

```
private List<E> myList = new ArrayList<E>();//just a local variable of MyClass

public MyClass<E> methodFromInterface(Interface<E> Obj) {
    MyClass<E> ooo = (MyClass<E>) obj;
}
```

The main problem I am facing is I have some variables in MyClass and though I am typecasting interface reference to MyClass I am not able access these variables.
Am I going wrong some where?

Comment: Show the full code of the interface and how you implement it.

Comment: If you are within the class `MyClass`, you should be able to access the `myList` variable. Otherwise you won't be able to because it is `private`.

Comment: I am in myclass and I am implementing this method. Do I have to write getters / setters then?

Comment: Also, your question title isn't very good IMO. Might I suggest "Unable to access instance variables after typecast".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your interface looks like this:

```
public interface MyInterface<E> {
    MyClass<E> methodFromInterface(Interface<E> Obj);
}
```

Then you can write code like this to access `myList` variable:

```
public MyClass<E> implements MyInterface<E> {

    private List<E> myList = new ArrayList<E>();

    public MyClass<E> methodFromInterface(MyInterface<E> obj) {
        MyClass<E> ooo = (MyClass<E>) obj;

        // now you can access 2 different instances of `myList`
        List<E> firstInstance = this.myList; 
        List<E> secondInstance = ooo.myList;
        // note that these will not be the same instance of a List!
    }
}
```

**DISCLAIMER:** I must add though that this seems like a very bad structure for your classes. It seems odd to me to have an `interface` with a method defined on it which takes an instance of itself and returns a sub-type. I think you might need to do some more learning about inheritance, interfaces, super-types, etc.